# Bind right click with Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material.

I would like to create a directive which will permit me to bind a right-click on an element.

I tried this :

#### JS:

```
app.directive('rightClick', ["$parse", function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.rightClick);
            element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    fn($scope, {$event:event});
                });
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

#### HTML:

```
<md-menu md-position-mode="target-right bottom">
<md-button right-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" aria-label="Open some menu">
    Right click
</md-button>
<md-menu-content>
    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="doSomething()" aria-label="Do something">
            Action
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
</md-menu-content>
```

The problem is that the menu doesn't appear on a good position.

In fact, the position is in the top left of the page and not on the element that I clicked.

How can I create a directive to do exactly the same thing that *ng-click* does but with a right-click and permits me to use Angular Material methods?

### UPDATE:

Thanks for your answer Catmandu.

I had create a similar directive but it still does not work.

Here is an illustration of my problem :

A result with custom "ng-right-click" directive who bind contextmenu:

[image: ng-right-click result]

A result with AngularJS "ng-click" directive:

[image: ng-click result]

On my custom directive, the menu doesn't appear on a good top/left position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a directive to bind specific action on right click, using the `contextmenu` event :

```
app.directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
        element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Use direct return function and avoid using restrict